# How to get base64 code by an img tag from DOM?

Tags: javascript, image, base64

I have an image link (./kcaptcha/) that gives me random image with numbers on each query. So, I want to get base64 code from DOM, not from image src/url. Is there any options to achieve it?[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olIvI.png)

Comment: We can't help you if you don't give us more information like a example of you' DOM ?

Comment: I want to decode a captcha image, using already downloaded to DOM image. This img tag gives me always a new image 
<img id="imgCaptcha" src="./kcaptcha/">

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you work with a  tag that looks like this:

```js
const myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

myBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const c = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  const img = document.getElementById("myImg");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  alert(c.toDataURL("image/png"));
})
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://picsum.photos/200" crossorigin="Anonymous"/>
<br>
<button id="myBtn">Get B64</button>
```

`crossorigin="Anonymous"` is mandatory